# Why don't my links show up in IE 9?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

Why don't my links show up in IE 9?

http://uk2canadapensiontransfers.com/index.php

If you don't want to view the website you can go directly to the style sheet at...

http://uk2canadapensiontransfers.com/css/style.css

The problem doesn't occur in any of the other IEs.

Comment: which links? have you tried to inspect the dom?

Comment: Seems to be all links. What is inspecting the dom?

Comment: press f12. that accesses the developer tools.

Comment: It's a Cufon issue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cufon doesn't work in IE9 for some reason. Downloading the more recent version 'should' solve your problem but personally I would use a Google Font instead.

Alternatively you can try either of these methods:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript">
Cufon.set('engine', 'canvas');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Force IE to render as an older version

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Look right at the bottom of your stylesheet to find and remove

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
a{color:black;}
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: That code is an attempted solution to the problem, which existed before I added that.